# Error: unable to verify the first certificate in Node-Red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am trying to call RESTful service (out side of my domain) in a simple Node-Red flow.

The flow is illustrated in the following diagram:
[image]

The function for calling the service:

```
var data = {};
data[“someparameter”] = “somevalue”;
msg.method = "POST";
msg.headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
msg.payload = JSON.stringify(data);
msg.url = "https://myserviceip/myendpoint/mymethod”;
return msg;
```

Nonetheless i get the following error:

```
"Error: unable to verify the first certificate : https://myserviceip/myendpoint/mymethod"
```

Setting the msg.rejectUnauthorized in the header to false did not work.

```
msg.rejectUnauthorized = false;  // to avoid the error but it does not work
```

Comment: More information is required here, I assume the function node is feeding into a http-request node?

Comment: Thanks @hardill, as requested the flow is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having had a look at the http-request node I don't think it's possible at the moment based on a flag in the incoming message, but it can be done in the node editor. Double click on the http-request node, then tick the "Enable secure (SSL/TLS) connection" checkbox. Next create a new TLS Config and then uncheck the "Verify server certificate" checkbox.

Save all that and it should work

But having said that I don't think it would be that hard to update the http-request node to support the `msg.rejectUnauthorized`. I'll look at sticking a pull request in (https://github.com/node-red/node-red/pull/1207).

Comment: @Future2020 I've updated my answer as I've been digging some more